# Is there an official public list of US physicians?

Tags: data

Where do [Healthgrades](https://www.healthgrades.com/) and [Vitals](http://vitals.com/) get their physician list from? Is there a publicly available central repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several sources for publicly available health practitioner databases. One of the most common sources is from the US government, which assigns a National Provider Identification (NPI) number to all medical practitioners. There is an online database you can use here:

https://npiregistry.cms.hhs.gov/

Enter a doctor's name, and you'll see a lot of information about them.

Comment: thanks. this does not include medical school information. do you know where that can be found?

Comment: You are correct. That information is located in the AMA Physician MasterFile. That contains information about residency, fellowship, board certification, and medical school.

Comment: gotcha. and unfortunately that is a paid service, correct?

Comment: While that is a paid service, you can get much of the same information here: http://certificationmatters.org/

Comment: certificationmatters.org tries to prevent screen scraping, but such blocks are generally not hard to get around.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this [dataset](https://public.acho.io/embed/4373ea74db8551d78b6e535a67b69519bb3136957a70d56aad09322049e0dc2c74e48943b117c10b5e745ced55273f37e1d3f34876cb7879b0051a9dfbd9247b) provided by Unibit. It contains information of all data providers in the US. It includes data about individual practitioners and organizations, such as their names, contact information, specialties, license, and so on.

Comment: You can try it for $100, that is.